# javascript function call assigned to variable returns undefined

Tags: javascript, testing, undefined, mocha.js

I am attempting to run a function in test environment (Mocha) and am running into an issue with calling my function when it is assigned to a variable (the test that is set up does the variable assignment).  I'm sure this has been answered somewhere else, but every example I see is an asynchronous function, which this is not.  The following code returns the object, but also undefined.  I suspect that it is the "undefined" output that prevents my code from running in the test suite.  Where is that undefined coming from, and is the correct output coming from the return statement or the console.log call?

```
var addTo = function(obj){
  var object = {};
  for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    for(key in arguments[i]){
      if(arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(key)){
        object[key] = arguments[i][key];
      }
    }
  }
  return object;
}

var myObj = addTo({name: "John"}, {location: "space", age: 35});
console.log(myObj);

//returns:  
//Object {name: "John", location: "space", age: 35}
//undefined
```

I know there is no real need to create an empty object here, as I could just add to the first object that is input into the function and start the for loop at i = 1.  Just an attempt to fix the undefined issue (which is only what I think is the issue).  If this is a duplicate, please link me to the correct post, as I cannot find it.

Comment: You're sure the `undefined` isn't just the return of the `console.log()` function call in your test enviroment ?

Comment: Well, I'm seeing the undefined when I run this through my Chrome console, which I'm doing because all I get back from my test environment is a rex "X" indicating that the function doesn't pass the test.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you're running this, but if you type `console.log()` in the console, you'll get `undefined` back, as that's what the function returns, and I think that's what you're seeing, but I'm in no way sure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console evaluates the expression and prints that. Since console.log doesn't return anything it displays undefined.

1. You forgot var in front of the 'key' variable. This is making it global.
2. I see you use semi-colons so add one after the } on line 11.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with the var in front of the "key" variable.  Thank you so much!